# Rendering desktop/screen/application to Directx?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, hook, overlay

First off, sorry for any grammatical/spelling mistakes, English is not my main tongue.
The goal i want to accomplish is to be able to display an external application or a desktop as an overlay on a external full screen Directx surface, and still be able to use the application/desktop inside the Directx-window.

Having a very little experience in Directx (i'm working on it) i'm struggling to find the best method to accomplish this task.

What i got so far is to try to use the [desktop duplication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display inside the Directx window, by hooking the EndScene method to add the stream from the desktop.

Is it possible to have full control over the external application inside the direcx window?
Is this possible to accomplish with a respectable frame rate? 
Is there any examples of trying to accomplish this?
Are there a better way?

Any answers is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!